# Gmail API Rendering of Message Has No Formatting

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I am using PHP and the Gmail API to retrieve a message. I am finding that when I decode the message body that there is no formatting so the message looks really bad when I render it. I want the message to look the same on my system as it does inside of Gmail. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
$service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$message = $service->users_messages->get("me", $messageId);

$messagePayload = $message->getPayload();
$headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
$parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();

$body = $parts[0]['body'];
$rawData = $body->data;
$sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
$decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);

echo $decodedMessage;
```

The $decodedMessage has no formatting, its just links and plain text.

Comment: You need to find the HTML part.

Comment: find the entry in $parts where the mimeType is "text/html". Try it manually via https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get to see the structure of the object which gets returned.

Comment: Also the API just returns the different parts of the message. If there are separate pictures, attachments etc, they will be in a different "part", so you may need to fetch those as well to get the full content of the message.